# Difference between a == 'foo' and 'foo' == a in javascript

Tags: javascript, optimization, minify

This is a basic stuff but I found it worth sharing with you all. I observed that a code compression utility changed a code fragement where a condition is written like,

```
if(document.getElementById('foo').value == '6')
```

to

```
if('6' == document.getElementById('foo').value)
```

In what way would that help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's to avoid an assignement and get an error if you miss one of the two `=`.

```
if('6' = document.getElementById('foo'))
```

won't pass (assigning to a literal), but

```
if(document.getElementById('foo') = '6')
```

will silently fail.

Comment: That's a valid case. Thank you @grasGendarme

Comment: I know some people write their comparisons "backwards" to avoid an accidental assignment, but it's a little weird that a utility would do this.  There were two `=` to start with; were they worried you would go back and remove one later?

Comment: Its funny, we were just talking about this at work today where an old contractor did if(null == someVal) in some java code.  I know this is a throw-back to C/C++ where the if statement would accept any value, and evaluated 1 to true and anything else to false.  But, I know in the case of Java, the expression HAS to evaluate to a boolean, so it's sort of a moot point.  I am of the impression that this makes the code look strange, and I would rather "risk" the chance I miss an '=' in a comparison, which I frankly think is unlikely, then make the code harder to understand.

Comment: Yes it's an old habit from C where anything evaluating to 0 (like an assignement) was considered as false. This might not make much sense in the day of javascript or java.

Comment: In JavaScript you can still do `if (x=1)` because of type coercion.  (That's a bit different than C where `if` accepts a number since there *was* no native boolean type prior to C99).  But in C#, like Java, `if` requires a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

The `==` in javascript is not "strongly typed", in opposition to `===`.

For exemple :

```
if (1 == '1')
{
    //Will pass here.
}

if (1 === '1')
{
   //Will not pass here
}
```

So the `==` implies that one of the two operand is casted in the type of the other.

The only difference I can see between `'foo' == a`and `a == 'foo'` is that in one case `a` is casted to string, and in the other case `'foo'` is casted to wathever is the type of `a`.